# CPP : arithmetic operation on empty vector size() output giving undefined behavior

Tags: c++, vector

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> nums;
    cout<<"size="<<nums.size()<<"\n";
    cout <<"diff1 = "<<0-2<<"\n";
    cout<<"diff2 = "<<nums.size()-2<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
size=0
diff1 = -2
diff2 = 18446744073709551614
```

Expected output diff2 = -2
Not sure how this output is getting generated.
I haven't seen this type of behavior.

Comment: It's because size() return a size_t (unsigned type).

Comment: Do you know about integer over/underflow?

Comment: Unrelated and maybe you didn't know it, but you included the _whole_ standard library in this small example for no reason. You might want to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: This is actually well defined behaviour, not undefined behaviour. Obviously it's surprising behaviour for you, but that doesn't mean its undefined.

Comment: Thanku everyone, I missed this crucial info.

Comment: @churill Thanks for including additional info
Will keep this mind

Answer (score 4):

`nums.size()` returns an unsigned type (actually `size_t`). Unsigned types have a smallest possible value of zero, so there's an issue when you try to generate a negative unsigned value. What the standard says is that the value *wraps around*. So a value of -1 converted to an unsigned type is the largest value that unsigned type can have, and similarly a value of -2 would be the second largest value that unsigned type can have.

That's what you are seeing in your output.

Comment: strictly speaking, the type is a `std::vector<int>::size_type` which, indeed has to be `unsigned`, but might not be `size_t`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I thought that unless you had a custom allocator `size_type` had to be `size_t`. That was the case in C++98 but I've not kept up with developments since then,

Answer (score 2):

No the behaviour is not undefined.

It's just that `nums.size()` is an `unsigned` type (formally a `std::vector<int>::size_type`), and the expression `num.size() - 2` is evaluated in `unsigned` arithmetic due to the rules of *implicit conversions*. `-1` in this case is `std::numeric_limits<std::vector<int>::size_type>::max()` and `-2` is one less than that, which accounts for your output (2<sup>64</sup> - 2). This *wrap-around* behaviour of `unsigned` arithmetic is defined by the C++ standard.

As a rule of thumb, using negatives in `unsigned` arithmetic is best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

```
 (nums.size()-2 ) will be unsigned why because nums.size() is unsigned.
```

and this will lead to below operator function of ostream

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned int value );
```

that's why you have unsigned result. if you want to see `-2` then cast num.size() as int
`((int)nums.size()-2)` will result `-2`

more detail you can check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt